# Phone 8.1 menu Flyout Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want a menu item on the share button to include email and txt I have seen this can be down in runtime but can  it be done in 8.1 silverlight?.
Uppon click the share button I wish to have a popup menu appear with sms and email appear thanks –

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
<shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Assets/icons/share.png" Text="Share">
        </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/icons/feature.settings.png" Text="settings" >
        </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>


    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question , could you be more specific about what you really want to achieve ?

Comment: @BurakKaanKöse Uppon click the share button I wish to have  a popup menu appear with sms and email appear thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <ListBox>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Mail"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="SomethingElse"></ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>

        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I am not able to try this because of my environment right now , but I don't remember any restrictions about AppBars on SDK side.